# ralink 148f:760b mt7601 driver not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, ralink

I got new ralink mini WIFI dongle.

lsusb returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:760b Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

it's based on MT7601UM chip.

driver installed following :[this instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation) does not work.

Any suggestions apart from buying older dongle?

I've tried it on 10.04(linuxcnc)
and 14.04 x64

some diags:

```
dmesg | grep -e mt7     
mt7601Usta: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
```

modprobe returns nothing

```
lsmod | grep mt76
mt7601Usta            807204  0
```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/691158/archer-t2u-stopped-working

Answer (score 1):

I also had a lot of time trying to put that dongle to work.

The driver is outdated and doesn't have the signature for the ID 148f:760b.

So following the same instructions but before 'make' you need to edit the file

> ./common/rtusb_dev_id.c

and add the line

```
{USB_DEVICE(0x148f,0x760b)}, /* 360 wifi */
```

after the block

```
#ifdef MT7601U
    {USB_DEVICE(0x148f,0x6370)}, /* Ralink 6370 */
    {USB_DEVICE(0x148f,0x7601)}, /* MT 6370 */
```

Then after 'make install' and when plugging the dongle you can confirm the installation by running ifconfig. The new device might appear as ra0. If it shows the MAC address as all zeros you can run 'ifconfig ra0 up' and check again.

Hope it helps.