# Kernel panic after wifi installation

Tags: wireless, kernel, ralink

after installing ralink WiFi adapter (Digitus DN-7042-1 Rev2 = 148f:7601) following this link:
 [Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation)
the system's (Kubuntu 14.04) kernel panics and switches to text console when a program accesses the Internet.

What to do, friends of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the (external) driver is buggy and is causing your system to crash; [you're not alone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation#comment653379_457061).(1)

To undo the thing you should remove the driver you compiled (it should be called `mt7601Usta.ko`, and live somewhere under `/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net` (adapt for your kernel version). After that, `depmod -a` and a reboot should let you as before (I mean, no wifi but no kernel panics).

(1) which is not surprising; the driver has a date of September 2013, and the linux kernel evolves really fast. This is a problem of out-of-tree drivers; they must be really developed and cared of day-by-day to be useful. Bug the manufacturer so that they add the driver to the official kernel tree...

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. Removing driver worked. I bugged the manufacturer, but that (I guess) will not result in a quick fix.

Comment: How exactly would they add the driver to the official kernel tree?

And: the patch mentions the date march 2014 (https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=25dde84d12f6ed3b&id=25DDE84D12F6ED3B!8315&ithint=file,.patch&authkey=!AC8SnU5poWC55VU). Who was working on that patch? user289087?