# HOW TO: ralink 148f:7601 wifi adaptor installation

Tags: wireless

I am a new Ubuntu user and doing my first steps slowly...
I have a wireless usb like in this issue with the same problem.

[Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation?newreg=110700a9bbed4d93abe8f6eea0e0692e)

After read it, I tried to follow the steps but i had problems...

1. I downloaded driver and patch on downloads and moved to `/tmp`
2. I went to terminal then typed...

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic build-essential
   cd /tmp
   tar xjf DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913.tar.bz2
   cd DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/
   ```

but in this step I don't know what to do. I have to change `~/(ADD THE PATH)` for anything?

```
patch -p0 < ~/(ADD THE PATH)/rt2870-mt7601Usta-kuid_t-kgid_t.patch
```