# how to install drivers for wifi adaptor Ralink 148f:7601 on ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, drivers

Recently, i bought a wifi adaptor,but as a result of new to ubuntu , i have no idea about how to

install drivers to run the wifi adaptor. Following some instructions from others, i used

`lsusb`to check out the chips id of the wifi adaptor.Here it is:`ID 148f:7601`,and i dont' know

what to do next,hope someone could help fix this problem.Thanks!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation