# Ralink 148f:7601 WIFI Dongle

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, 14.10, ralink

I've followed the procedure in [Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation) in order to install the appropriate driver for my brand new Ralink WIFI Dongle.

I downloaded the source code from http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/mt7601u-usb/ (and eventually tried a patch from http://www.mediafire.com/download/fezezv1u28y7eey/rt2870-mt7601Usta-kuid_t-kgid_t.patch, even though it seems only to work with version 20130913).

But it won't compile on 14.10:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic build-essential
tar xjf mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.tar.bz2
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
```

Returns the following:

```
  ...
  CC [M]  /home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow’:
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5401:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                                     ^
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5401:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                                               ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic'
Makefile:393: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

The patch fixes *this* error, but produces something new:

```
tar xjf mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.tar.bz2
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
patch -p0 < ../rt2870-mt7601Usta-kuid_t-kgid_t.patch
make
```

Returns the following:

```
  ...
  CC [M]  /home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.o
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘Set_DriverVersion_Proc’:
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:47:97: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_TRACE, ("Driver version-%s %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__));
                                                                                                 ^
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:47:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_TRACE, ("Driver version-%s %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__));
 ^
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘Set_DebugFunc_Proc’:
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1084:2: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat=]
  DBGPRINT_S(RT_DEBUG_TRACE, ("Set RTDebugFunc = 0x%x\n", RTDebugFunc));
  ^
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘set_rf’:
/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:5960:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘UCHAR *’ [-Wformat=]
   rv = sscanf(arg, "%d-%d-%x", &(bank_id), &(rf_id), &(rf_val));
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.o] Error 1
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/dudektria/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.patched/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic'
Makefile:393: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Can someone help me out on this? I give more information about my system below:

```
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can give more information in case it's necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fantastic! I was too busy searching for something with "Ralink" in it that I haven't found that question!
The solution there solves my problem in a very elegant way.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.