# TOTOLINK N150UA wireless USB adapter unable to install in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, usb, ralink

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside my windows 7 on my PC(CPU INTEL i686 Mainboard is MS-7519). The wireless works flawless on windows but there is no sign of it on Ubuntu. Any help to fix this issue would help a lot. Regards.

Thank you Pilot6, this is the output:

walter@nono01:~$ lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command when the dongle is inserted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ralink 148f:7601 wifi adaptor installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation)