# I have a Ralink Wireless Lan USB Adapter that I can't get to work no matter what I try

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, usb, ralink

I am new to linux so there are many things that I may or may not have done correctly, but I have gone through many solutions on installing this driver for the USB adapter, however, I never have the option to go and choose a WiFi network.

I tried using the manufacturer's driver, it was outdated so I had to use a third party fix. It looked like it worked, but I couldn't detect any networks.

I then tried to use the Windows Wireless Driver program, then it notifies me that all the drivers are incorrect. Surely there has to be something that can be done to fix this driver or network detection issue?

My "lsusb" output

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0182 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My "usb-devices | awk '/0182/' RS="  output

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=06 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=0182 Rev=81.9c
S:  Manufacturer=Generic
S:  Product=USB2.0-CRW
S:  SerialNumber=20060413092100000
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

My "usb-devices | awk '/148f/' RS=" output

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=148f ProdID=7601 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=MediaTek
S:  Product=802.11 n WLAN
S:  SerialNumber=1.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=160mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 8 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Your adapter is not 8192CU. It is `Ralink`. Please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/148f/' RS=`

Comment: possible duplicate of [ralink 148f:7601 wifi adaptor installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation)

Comment: added the output, looking into the ralink thread for an answer

Comment: So it is `Ralink` aka `Mediatek`.

Comment: thanks for the help, the thread you linked me to got it working

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already answered but I found an easier solution. There's a PPA with the correct driver here: https://code.launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/mt7601

So, all you have to do is type this on console:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:thopiekar/mt7601
apt update
apt install mt7601
```