# How to install wlan driver mt7601u ? file(mt7601Usta.ko) is missing while doing it

Tags: wireless, drivers, mediatek

How to install wlan driver mt7601u ? file(mt7601Usta.ko) is missing while doing it?

i am facing a problem while setting up wlan connection for my new mediatek wlan adapter .

unable to setup the connection , while making it was showing that file is missing .

when i replaced the file which is downloaded externally from online , it is prompting as a invalid file .

help me to go wireless

Comment: Did you try this method? http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adapter-installation/554278#554278

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adapter-installation/554278#554278  i have already tried this but i said that one file is missing mt7601Usta.ko .

Comment: Duplicate of [Ralink 148f:7601 wifi adapter installation](http://askubuntu.com/q/457061/65926). I posted [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/690576/65926) with an alternative installation method.

Answer (score 2):

There's a PPA with this driver. At least it worked for me. Connect via ethernet and run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:thopiekar/mt7601
sudo apt-get-update
sudo apt-get install mt7601-sta-dkms
```

The driver for this adapter was included in kernel 4.2. If you upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 you just have to download a firmware file:

```
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin https://github.com/porjo/mt7601/raw/master/src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin
```

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 or later there's no need to install or download anything.

Comment: I am afraid this driver won't build on new kernels for some reason. Kernel 4.2 has a native support.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I've used this PPA on Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04. On Ubuntu 15.10 the adapter works out of the box. I already posted [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/690576/65926) on another question and marked this one as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 15.10, and it doesn't work out of the box because the mt7601u.bin firmware file is missing. What package is supposed to provide that file?

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ I updated the answer on the [duplicate question](http://askubuntu.com/a/690576/65926).  Seems like I already had the firmware file from a previous manual installation.

Comment: for 14.04 i have upgraded the kernel using this post http://askubuntu.com/a/696253/247787, restarted,  downloaded a firmware file like described above, restarted again, it worked.

Comment: I'm using 16.04, getting this error: `ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic is not supported`,