# When will 4.2.0 kernel be available for 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I wonder when will linux-image-generic-lts-wily be available for Trusty? Are there any ETA?

Comment: As soon as the maintainers decide. It should be soon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The approved answer is wrong. The packages are **available** right now!
Just

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

However note that they will not be officially *supported* until the 14.04.4 point release is out. Until then they are in the "early preview" phase.

Comment: Perhaps your mirorr is behind, I got it from my local ubuntu mirror under trusty-updates. Also look [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/security/linux-generic-lts-wily).

Comment: The answer was correct when it was written. Now it is true.

Comment: Thank's for mentioning that lts-wily packages are already on mirrors!

Comment: They're available for testing purposes only. The release schedule is clear in the Wiki. Be aware that installing them now will produces a lot of issues (I've already tested several kernels before the LTS Enablement Stack release, and ALWAYS rolled back due system freezes).

Comment: I'm using them right now and they are working fine.

Comment: Getting some error,"Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch"

Answer (score 6):

## LTS Enablement Stack

Wily kernel+drivers are now available as stable since 2016, Feb, 18.

You should always wait until Canonical provides a stable backport, like this, of the kernel+**drivers** released in the edge/six-month releases for the LTS versions: the **[LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)**.

According instructions, install with:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386
```

## PPA

There is a Canonical kernel team PPA to test the kernel, but you should **not** use it. The PPA description is clear about it:

```
This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels.

It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA.
```

I.e., use it at your own risk. I tested in the past, and got several freezes.

Comment: That is not correct. 4.2 will be available much earlier. It will be default in 14.04.4 in Feb, 2016.

Comment: @Pilot6 As I stated.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha No, you stated that it will be available as a stable point release in February 2016.  The short answer is "It will be available when it's published to the trusty repositories, which will happen some time before the 14.04.4 point release in February 2016".  Your answer is imprecise.

Comment: No, it's clear in the Wiki. I've used this wiki for Enablement Stack since 12.04 and it's very precise. But you're free to disagree.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one: it lets the reader learn more by following the more general link, which will work even when Trusty reaches its EOL.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** it will be available in main repository for trusty within a week or two.

It is already available in ppa. You can install it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

It will get to main repository when the maintainers decide to upload it there.

**Update:** The 4.2 kernels are **NOW** available in main repositories.

Comment: You mean when they bug-fix and bug-check it.  It likely needs a good bit of work before releasing ;)

Comment: Well, the Ubuntu kernel 4.2 has been released already. The packages for 14.04 are uploaded for early testing. It is optional anyway.

Comment: right, but I meant that it needs testing/bugfixing probably before they release it as 'available' and optional (but not into -proposed).  :P

Comment: Actually I do not think anybody will do that ;-). The kernel is already being tested in 15.10. And users will test it and report bugs.

Comment: Just one friendly reminder: this PPA has the following mention `This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels. It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA.`