# Ubuntu Wifi driver offline install

Tags: wireless

I've bought an wifi receiver for my pc. Model no. Edup EP-N8553. Here are the screenshot of the driver files. how to install this? is it possible to install it without any kind of internet? Please help. [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHYBC.png)

Comment: What's in the README_STA_usb?

Comment: Provide information as text rather than image(s) (readable, searchable, etc).

Answer (score 0):

People on the Raspbery Pi forums [are saying](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=122028&p=823547&hilit=mt7601#p823513) this wifi dongle works with the mt7601u driver which is included in kernel 4.2.  You didn't include any information about which version of Ubuntu you are using, so I'll give you a few different options here:

The dongle will *probably* work without any configuration on 16.04 based on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672021/how-to-install-wlan-driver-mt7601u-filemt7601usta-ko-is-missing-while-doing).

Earlier releases will take one or two steps:

If you are using 14.04, you will need to first upgrade to the 4.2 kernel or the 4.4 kernel.  (I find the 4.2 kernel to be more stable on my computer).  To install a kernel update offline, go to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and get the necessary packages. For example, to get the 4.2 kernel, download these packages to install offline:

```
linux-headers-4.2.0-35
linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic
linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic
linux-firmware
```

You do not need to upgrade the kernel for 15.04 or 15.10.

For all releases prior to 16.04, you will probably need to download the latest mt7601 firmware using the instructions from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672021/how-to-install-wlan-driver-mt7601u-filemt7601usta-ko-is-missing-while-doing), which I have modified for offline install.  First download the latest firmware: 
https://github.com/porjo/mt7601/raw/master/src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin

Then transfer it to your offline computer: (replace *filename* with the location of the file you downloaded onto your usb drive or whatever.)

```
sudo cp filename /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

I don't have an Edup EP-N8553 to test this with, so I cannot guarantee that these steps will work, but it does seem that other people on the internet were having success getting this dongle working this way.