# I am installing Wifi driver but error on make in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, make

```
ghost@ghost:~/Desktop$ cd DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913
ghost@ghost:~/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913$ make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools'
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘announce_802_3_packet’:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:331:16: warning: unused variable ‘pAd’ [-Wunused-variable]
  RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd = (RTMP_ADAPTER *)pAdSrc;
                ^
In file included from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘STA_MonPktSend’:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:399:35: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION_
                                   ^
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/os/rt_linux.h:661:16: note: in definition of macro ‘DBGPRINT_RAW’
         printk Fmt;               \
                ^
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:399:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBGPRINT’
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION_
         ^
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/auth.o
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/auth_rsp.o
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sync.o
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c: In function ‘PeerBeacon’:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c:2180:12: warning: passing argument 8 of ‘StaAddMacTableEntry’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            ie_list,
            ^
In file included from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rt_config.h:59:0,
                 from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c:28:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rtmp.h:7892:9: note: expected ‘IE_LISTS * {aka struct _IE_lists *}’ but argument is of type ‘BCN_IE_LIST * {aka struct _bcn_ie_list *}’
 BOOLEAN StaAddMacTableEntry(
         ^
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.o
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c: In function ‘STAHandleRxDataFrame’:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:523:33: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘MacTableLookup’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    pEntry = MacTableLookup(pAd, &pHeader->Addr2);
                                 ^
In file included from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rt_config.h:59:0,
                 from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:28:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rtmp.h:8429:18: note: expected ‘UCHAR * {aka unsigned char *}’ but argument is of type ‘UCHAR (*)[6] {aka unsigned char (*)[6]}’
 MAC_TABLE_ENTRY *MacTableLookup(RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd, UCHAR *pAddr);
                  ^
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/connect.o
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlRF’:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5306:32: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘LONG {aka long int}’ [-Wformat=]
       sprintf(msg+strlen(msg), "BANK%d_R%02d:%02X  ", bank_Id, rfId, rfValue);
                                ^
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5359:27: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘RtmpDrvAllRFPrint’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   RtmpDrvAllRFPrint(NULL, msg, strlen(msg));
                           ^
In file included from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rt_config.h:64:0,
                 from /home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:28:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/include/rt_os_util.h:668:6: note: expected ‘UINT32 * {aka unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘PSTRING {aka char *}’
 VOID RtmpDrvAllRFPrint(
      ^
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5209:22: warning: unused variable ‘rf_bank’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UCHAR    regRF = 0, rf_bank = 0;
                      ^
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow’:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5766:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 intf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, _
                                                                     ^
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5766:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 , size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                     ^
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RtmpIoctl_rt_ioctl_siwgenie’:
/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7610:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     eid_ptr = pAd->StaCfg.pWpaAssocIe;
             ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ghost/Desktop/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic'
Makefile:394: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Comment: I have fixed the formatting of your question but please help to improve it by adding some context: what device do you have? what driver and version are you trying to build and where did you get it? what is your kernel version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink 148f:7601 wifi adapter installation](http://askubuntu.com/a/690576/65926)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink 148f:7601 wifi adapter installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adapter-installation)

Answer (score 2):

From your kernel version, 4.2.0-16, it appears that you are running Ubuntu 15.10. The driver `mt7601u` is already built in. See if it is currently loaded:

```
lsmod | grep mt7
```

If not load it:

```
sudo modprobe mt7601u
```

Check to see if the required firmware is missing:

```
dmesg | grep mt7
```

If it is missing, with a temporary working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601
cd mt7601/src/mcu/bin
sudo mv MT7601.bin  /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

Now unload and reload the driver so it sees the firmware:

```
sudo modprobe -r mt7601u
sudo modprobe mt7601u
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:( ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter)
./os/linux/Makefile.6:
add line as below
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types -Wno-date-time

Comment: Hey. This was able to help me pass the ` macro "__DATE__" might prevent` error. But now I have a new error - `rt_linux.c:1142:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kgid_t {aka const struct <anonymous>}’
   pOSFSInfo->fsgid = current_fsgid();` Can you help?