# WiFi Driver is not installing Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, 15.10

```
ghost@ghost:~$ lsmod | grep mt7
mt7601u                98304  0
mac80211              733184  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              548864  2 mac80211,mt7601u
ghost@ghost:~$ dmesg | grep mt7
[  770.040520] mt7601u 2-1.6:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[  770.042066] mt7601u 2-1.6:1.0: Direct firmware load for mt7601u.bin failed with error -2
[  770.042759] mt7601u: probe of 2-1.6:1.0 failed with error -2
[  770.042893] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
ghost@ghost:~$
```

What I missed here

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: isn't this fix your issue [http://askubuntu.com/questions/708795/i-am-installing-wifi-driver-but-error-on-make-in-ubuntu-15-10]
possible duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink 148f:7601 wifi adapter installation](http://askubuntu.com/a/690576/65926)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink 148f:7601 wifi adapter installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adapter-installation)

Answer (score 0):

you have to copy firmware to /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin from driver_source/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin

Comment: Kindly explain more on how to copy this file exactly, what copying will achieve or how it will solve the problem.