# wi fi not detected in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, usb, ralink

```
root@satish-G41M-Combo:~# lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller [8086:2e30] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5000]
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2e32] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:a000]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 [8086:27d2] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-D525TUD [1458:5004]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-D525TUD [1458:5004]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-D525TUD [1458:5004]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-D525TUD [1458:5004]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-D525TUD [1458:5006]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller [8086:27df] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:b001]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:27c0] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:b002]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-8I945PG-RH/GA-D525TUD Mainboard [1458:5001]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v1.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1073] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: There is no built-in Wi-Fi module. Do you ask about a USB dongle?

Comment: yes sir wireless usb adapter

Comment: You should have mentioned this before. Then please add output of `lsusb`.

Comment: satish@satish-G41M-Combo:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1

Comment: Please delete this comment and add output to your question. It is unreadable here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink 148f:7601 wifi adapter installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adapter-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Check out that the wireless is not disabled by the physical hardware switch.
In this case run the following command, to check whether the wireless is soft blocked or hard blocked:-

```
himanshu_code@ubuntu15:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Check whether the  wifi is soft blocked or hard blocked, then run the following command:

```
 himanshu_code@ubuntu15:~$ sudo rfkill unblock <identity>
```

in my case it's 1

```
 himanshu_code@ubuntu15:~$ sudo rfkill unblock 1
```

Restart the system.

Comment: root@satish-G41M-Combo:~# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no