# Wifi MediaTek adapter disappeared

Tags: 14.04, wireless, usb

I have a foxconn nanopc with a built-in wi-fi adapter, but it's weak so I use TP-Link TL-WN727N. After installing MediaTek drivers  everything was fine.

After today's Ubuntu update adapter is missing!
On Windows 7 (dualboot) all works fine.

Here is some information from the terminal:

`lsusb`:

`Bus 003 Device 006: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter`

`lspci`:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)
```

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

`lshw -class network`:

```
*-network               
       описание: Ethernet interface
       продукт: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       производитель: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       физический ID: 0
       сведения о шине: pci@0000:01:00.0
       логическое имя: eth0
       версия: 07
       серийный №: 30:0e:d5:be:be:05
       размер: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       разрядность: 64 bits
       частота: 33MHz
       возможности: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       кофигурация: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       ресурсы: IRQ:43 ioport:e000(размер=256) память:f0004000-f0004fff память:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       описание: Беспроводной интерфейс
       продукт: Centrino Wireless-N 2200
       производитель: Intel Corporation
       физический ID: 0
       сведения о шине: pci@0000:02:00.0
       логическое имя: wlan0
       версия: c4
       серийный №: 9c:4e:36:df:3b:68
       разрядность: 64 bits
       частота: 33MHz
       возможности: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       кофигурация: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-69-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       ресурсы: IRQ:46 память:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

`dmesg`:

```
[  104.865922] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  105.005497] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[  105.005507] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  105.005512] usb 3-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  105.005516] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[  105.005520] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  117.283374] wlan0: authenticate with 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4
[  117.288177] wlan0: send auth to 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4 (try 1/3)
[  117.292958] wlan0: authenticated
[  117.294702] wlan0: associate with 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4 (try 1/3)
[  117.300429] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=10)
[  117.321717] wlan0: associated
[  123.019300] wlan0: deauthenticating from 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  123.040553] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  123.046538] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  123.046544] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[  123.046546] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  123.046550] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  123.046553] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  123.046556] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  123.046558] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  123.046561] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  129.456184] wlan0: authenticate with 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4
[  129.460292] wlan0: send auth to 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4 (try 1/3)
[  129.468646] wlan0: authenticated
[  129.471111] wlan0: associate with 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4 (try 1/3)
[  129.490052] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 28:c6:8e:5b:2a:a4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=10)
[  129.514617] wlan0: associated
[  713.714410] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  717.750351] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  717.889808] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[  717.889819] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  717.889824] usb 3-2: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  717.889829] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[  717.889833] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  724.791847] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  729.624460] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  729.763901] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[  729.763911] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  729.763917] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  729.763922] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[  729.763926] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  738.183058] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  840.026416] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  840.165901] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[  840.165912] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  840.165917] usb 3-2: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  840.165922] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[  840.165926] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 1259.668469] systemd-hostnamed[3962]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

Comment: If that was a kernel update today, you may need to reinstall MediaTek drivers (all of them, not sure how many you have) , and hopefully, everything will be fine again.

Comment: >Now that Kernel 4.2 has been released which contains a driver for mt7601u

Comment: Why do you want the USB when you have a working internal device?

Comment: Becouse it's near ten times slower

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/690576/65926).

Comment: @eric-carvalho Yay yours link helps me !