# Wi-Fi kernel module installed but interface doesn't show up

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, interface

I'm currently trying to bring to life MT7601U Wi-Fi dongle. I have managed the module to work and `lsmod` shows that `mt7601Usta` is loaded (but the module reports `used by -> 0`). Now I'm having trouble with setting up the interface which doesn't show up in `ifconfig` nor `iwconfig` output.

I have followed this [guide](https://groenholdt.net/Computers/RaspberryPi/MediaTek-MT7601-USB-WIFI-on-the-Raspberry-Pi/MediaTek-MT7601-USB-WIFI-on-the-Raspberry-Pi.html) to configure the rest of the files, although the board in question is [Pine 64](http://pine64.com/). However, executing `sudo ifup ra0` gives following:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run_parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up ra0.
```

Is there something else that needs to be done so that the interface appears and can be used? The board is running Ubuntu and it seems to me like Linux / network related question as the hardware part is recognized.

Edit: The kernel in question is 3.10.x, so this dongle doesn't yet work 'out of box'.

Edit2: `lsusb` output as requested (only relevant output): `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter`

Edit3: Full [dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/AWQ5Mp2Q).

Comment: With the device inserted, please run: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to add the result. We wonder if the version of mt7601Usta that you compiled actually covers your device.

Comment: @chili555 added that info

Comment: Does your installation have the firmware file(s) mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation)? Something like `/lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin`

Comment: I added them them from the github repo (forks of original `porjo` repo). At least I hope that it's that (they are located in `src/mcu/bin` folder inside those repos)

Comment: Are there any clues in the message log? `sudo modprobe mt7601Usta && dmesg | grep mt76`

Comment: @chili555 Not with that command but I took a look at full `dmesg` output and there is `rt2870: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -1` and it seems like that is the usb port that the device is connected into. However, the `modprobe` command had no output.

Comment: Any other clues ? `dmesg | grep rt2` Did `make` proceed without error?

Comment: @chili555 I have edited the post with full dmesg output. Other than the probe failed, there is just usbcore reporting that it registered new interface driver rt2870 (it is few microseconds after the probe failed message)