# Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, ralink

I have updated my Ubuntu desktop from 14.04 to 16.04 and my Wi-Fi dongle stooped working.
I've tried to follow the instructions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation) but it did not work.

How can I make it work again?

Thanks guys.

**EDIT**

So far I've run these commands:

```
rfkill list all
sudo modprobe mt7601u && dmesg | grep mt76
```

The result was:

```
[   85.231948] mt7601Usta: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[10822.191654] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
```

Any idea of what to do next?

**EDIT2**

I disabled the secured boot and it's still not working.
The result of running the previous commands again is:

```
[  185.695417] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[  185.712356] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: firmware, attempted to load /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin, but failed with error -22
[  185.712362] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Direct firmware load for mt7601u.bin failed with error -22
[  185.712865] mt7601u: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -22
[  185.712917] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
```

Comment: Please open a terminal and run these commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `sudo modprobe mt7601u && dmesg | grep mt76` Next, edit your question to add the results.

Comment: Did you try " Additional Drivers " from Dash ?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in bios.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16?s=3|0.8819

Comment: No additional drivers.
Is it a kernel problem? If so how do I use earlier version of kernel to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was apparently the kernel that was corrupted because other stuff did not worked as well. I erased Ubuntu completely and than reinstalled 16.04 and the Wi-fi  dongle just works and no special installation to be done.

Thanks anyway for checking and putting your comments.

Comment: Thanks for posting your result here! That we know that it just went away can reduce much confusion.