# Ralink mt7601 Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, lubuntu, ralink

Hie everyone,

i upgrade my computer from 14.04 to Lubuntu 16.04 and I have the same problem with my Ralink mt7601u as [Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796657/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04), but I don't want reinstall computer.

```
iwconfig:

pc-rodina@pcrodina:~$ iwconfig
ra0       Ralink STA  
      Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I type ifconfig ra0 up and my iwconfig changed, but WiFi is not working:

```
pc-rodina@pcrodina:~$ iwconfig
ra0       Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:"MT7601STA"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

rfkill list all && sudo modprobe mt7601u && dmesg | grep mt76:

```
pc-rodina@pcrodina:~$ rfkill list all && sudo modprobe mt7601u &&      dmesg | grep mt76
[   15.414227] mt7601Usta: module verification failed: signature   and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  325.266072] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
```

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off SECURE BOOT in your BIOS and you will probably be fine... assuming that your Ralink driver is current.

In 16.04, it's now required that drivers be signed. Yours isn't. Did you compile the driver yourself? Are you using DKMS? Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I can't find SECURE BOOT in my BIOS, my motherboard is asus psl-mx . I tried compile driver, but wifi still not working.  I think, I don't use  DKMS.

Comment: Please review **http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules**, where they talk about the ASUS settings. If that can't be found, then use the mokutil utility described there also. Cheers, Al