# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) for Raspberry Pi 2 cannot get wifi working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lubuntu, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) for Rpi 2 and following the steps given at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi, I used the following commands in general to install:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
-To get WIFI firmware
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
But when the desktop installed I am unable to see my connected wifi dongle on the Rpi 2, the connection just gives the option to use via LAN/Ethernet Network.

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb`.  Do note that not all Wifi dongles will be supported by the package you installed.  It was just a general guideline.

Comment: Bus 001 Devvice 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter..
This should be the Wifi adapter, it is listing it.

Comment: And I have tried before on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for ARM it was working on it.

Comment: Ah, ok... then I have no answer.  I just see that Googling that particular Wifi Dongle seems to have a lot of instructions to get it working, including compiling.  That said, if you scroll downwards on this ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation ) answer, you'll see that from 16.04 you model ( 148f:7601 ) is indeed supported.  What does `ifconfig -a` tell you?

Comment: It shows eth0 and lo but doesn't display wireless

Comment: It might not have loaded a module.  What does `lsmod | grep rt` tell you?

Comment: It doesn't give any result

Comment: Okay, I'm guessing, because I'm not sure what module is right.  Try `sudo  modprobe rt2000`.  See whether you get results for lsmod and ifconfig -a.  Alternatively try `sudo modprobe mt7601Usta`.  (Module names come from the linked article)

Comment: modprob: FATAL: Module rt2000 not found

Comment: Did you try the other modprobe?  What was the result for that?
Just an idea, but have you tried installing the package `linux-firmware-nonfree`.  You need to add `multiverse` to your ubuntu repositories though, if you didn't already do so.

Comment: Wait, I am now realizing something.  You tried with 16.04 and it worked and that's confirmed as working in an article I linked for you.  That same article documents it's a pain to get working in 14.04, and you want to use 14.04...  Obviously 14.04 has an older kernel and less support for different hardware.  The answer is to use 16.04 or go through a painful installation process, that might not even work because of the architectural differences betweem ARM and x86/amd64.

Answer (score 2):

Following the lengthy comment thread, I am going to summarize it as follows:

You tried with 16.04 and it worked.  I don't even see how you could deduce from that, that it also should work on 14.04.  The dongle working on 16.04 is also confirmed in an [article I linked for you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation). That same article documents it's a pain to get working in 14.04.  Obviously 14.04 has an older kernel and less support for different hardware, on top of that the firmware is missing in the repositories.

The answer is to use 16.04 or go through a painful installation process, that might not even work because of the architectural differences between ARM and x86/amd64.

I won't say it's impossible to fix, but you're in for a rough ride if you want to run this particular dongle on Ubuntu 14.04/ARM.

Comment: Is there a list of compatible USB Wireless adapters available for Ubuntu 14.04 ARM?

Comment: Well, there is an "Official Raspberry Pi WiFi Adapter".  I'll link to the shop where I buy stuff.  I am not affiliated, just a happy customer.   https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-wifi/products/official-raspberry-pi-wifi-adapter