# Access point mode not supported

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

`iw list` results

```
Supported interface modes:
     * managed
     * monitor
```

AP mode is supported fine in windows and hotspot works fine.
Ralink usb adapter in use.

`ethtool -i wlan0 | grep driver` outputs `MT7601`

Does this driver support AP mode?.. Will changing the driver support AP mode?

This page http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/  list the drivers for my card. How do I install this? It seems Ubuntu already comes with the MT7601 driver shown in that page. If i install another driver, will it work? Is there a way to change the firmware from the terminal to rollback the driver to get a supported one? How do I know which all drivers supports my adapter?

Comment: Does `mt7601` family supported `managed, monitor` and along with `AP mode` in Linux ? I want to use it in kali Linux for wifi related staff. Please help and share your experience

Answer (score 4):

The in-tree `mt7601` kernel driver does not support AP mode yet.

But the vendor driver does support this mode. The problem is that Mediatek does not maintain the driver well enough. It does not build for new kernels.

But some people patch these drivers. If you search the web, you will find some github repos with the source.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation) for more information.

Comment: AFAIK, `mt7601` is work AP mode in windows, but not showing in Linux in `iw list`. It's due to drivers ? Does hardware has AP feature ?

Comment: The hardware has this feature, but Linux driver didn't.

Comment: But Same device working fine in window 10, Able to Make AP (Hotspot) but In the Linux, I unable to see `AP` interface mode (only `monitor` and `Managed` visible). If It's in windows then its should in Linux, that means `iw list` listed as per driver, not from hardware, I guess. Please share your view with this.

Comment: "If It's in windows then its should in Linux" is wrong.

Comment: Means : Consider that AP feature is available in windows, Hardware compatible AP mode. It's not visible in Linux then we can say AP feature available in hardware but not work in Linux due to Driver issue.