# TL-WN727N V4 very slow

Tags: networking, drivers

I tried installing driver for it from [official website](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN727N.html)
but it comes with same one currently installed. `lshw` shows that firmware is missing. any suggestions?

this is the output I get from `lshw`

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.4
       logical name: wlx60e327143441
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=[REMOVED] link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

`ifconfig -a`

```
wlx60e327143441 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [DELETED]  
          inet addr:192.168.0.144  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::62e3:27ff:fe14:3441/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6760968 (6.7 MB)  TX bytes:2321393 (2.3 MB)
```

`iwconfig`

```
wlx60e327143441  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TP-LINK_CF310C"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: [DELETED]   
          Bit Rate=40.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:220  Invalid misc:259   Missed beacon:0
```

`lsusb`

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter`

`lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cdc_acm                36864  0
mtnet7601Usta          45056  0
mt7601Usta           1028096  1 mtnet7601Usta
mtutil7601Usta         81920  2 mt7601Usta,mtnet7601Usta
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
xts                    16384  1
gf128mul               16384  1 xts
arc4                   16384  2
dm_crypt               28672  1
nvidia_uvm            745472  0
mt7601u               102400  0
mac80211              737280  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,mt7601u
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_hda_codec_via      24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_via
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
coretemp               16384  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             172032  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
joydev                 20480  0
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
snd                    81920  21 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
serio_raw              16384  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
asus_atk0110           20480  0
i7core_edac            24576  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
edac_core              53248  2 i7core_edac
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
nvidia_drm             45056  1
nvidia_modeset        765952  5 nvidia_drm
hid_generic            16384  0
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 nvidia_drm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
psmouse               126976  0
nvidia              11489280  91 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
usbhid                 49152  0
pata_acpi              16384  0
r8169                  81920  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
mii                    16384  1 r8169
pata_via               16384  0
fjes                   28672  0
```

`netstat -i`

```
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
enp2s0     1500 0         0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo        65536 0    470836      0      0 0        470836      0      0      0 LRU
wlx60e327143441  1500 0    185717      0      0 0        137901      0      0      0 BMRU
```

`netstat -s`

```
Ip:
    714498 total packets received
    23 with invalid addresses
    0 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    713746 incoming packets delivered
    684905 requests sent out
    112312 outgoing packets dropped
    90 dropped because of missing route
Icmp:
    227741 ICMP messages received
    88 input ICMP message failed.
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 227741
    230349 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
        destination unreachable: 230349
IcmpMsg:
        InType3: 227741
        OutType3: 230349
Tcp:
    7389 active connections openings
    2 passive connection openings
    2837 failed connection attempts
    832 connection resets received
    13 connections established
    218843 segments received
    174570 segments send out
    13329 segments retransmited
    7609 bad segments received.
    5293 resets sent
Udp:
    40470 packets received
    229661 packets to unknown port received.
    0 packet receive errors
    266654 packets sent
    IgnoredMulti: 1306
UdpLite:
TcpExt:
    86 ICMP packets dropped because they were out-of-window
    968 TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
    36 packets rejects in established connections because of timestamp
    3611 delayed acks sent
    1 delayed acks further delayed because of locked socket
    Quick ack mode was activated 5275 times
    38 packets directly queued to recvmsg prequeue.
    8340 bytes directly in process context from backlog
    7640 bytes directly received in process context from prequeue
    121876 packet headers predicted
    16 packets header predicted and directly queued to user
    13364 acknowledgments not containing data payload received
    4263 predicted acknowledgments
    266 times recovered from packet loss by selective acknowledgements
    Detected reordering 1 times using time stamp
    2 congestion windows fully recovered without slow start
    1 congestion windows partially recovered using Hoe heuristic
    79 congestion windows recovered without slow start by DSACK
    3559 congestion windows recovered without slow start after partial ack
    TCPLostRetransmit: 17
    22 timeouts after SACK recovery
    53 timeouts in loss state
    346 fast retransmits
    15 forward retransmits
    207 retransmits in slow start
    5156 other TCP timeouts
    TCPLossProbes: 3734
    TCPLossProbeRecovery: 182
    59 SACK retransmits failed
    5247 DSACKs sent for old packets
    149 DSACKs sent for out of order packets
    1773 DSACKs received
    17 DSACKs for out of order packets received
    427 connections reset due to unexpected data
    298 connections reset due to early user close
    822 connections aborted due to timeout
    TCPDSACKIgnoredOld: 40
    TCPDSACKIgnoredNoUndo: 574
    TCPSpuriousRTOs: 2
    TCPSackShiftFallback: 783
    TCPRetransFail: 49
    TCPRcvCoalesce: 53356
    TCPOFOQueue: 28487
    TCPOFOMerge: 149
    TCPChallengeACK: 6608
    TCPSYNChallenge: 7862
    TCPSpuriousRtxHostQueues: 3639
    TCPAutoCorking: 2629
    TCPSynRetrans: 5650
    TCPOrigDataSent: 21965
    TCPHystartTrainDetect: 1
    TCPHystartTrainCwnd: 20
    TCPHystartDelayDetect: 2
    TCPHystartDelayCwnd: 34
    TCPACKSkippedPAWS: 7
    TCPACKSkippedSeq: 11
    TCPACKSkippedChallenge: 1255
    TCPKeepAlive: 5284
IpExt:
    InMcastPkts: 3320
    OutMcastPkts: 1413
    InBcastPkts: 2134
    OutBcastPkts: 275
    InOctets: 288666073
    OutOctets: 60325645
    InMcastOctets: 466096
    OutMcastOctets: 230882
    InBcastOctets: 206129
    OutBcastOctets: 42884
    InNoECTPkts: 714498
```

### **UPDATE 1**

So Im installing `mt7601-sta-dkms` as suggested by @ThatGuy

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mt7601-sta-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/926 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6591 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mt7601-sta-dkms.
(Reading database ... 220122 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mt7601-sta-dkms_3.0.0.4-0~201602170733~rev26~pkg4~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mt7601-sta-dkms (3.0.0.4-0~201602170733~rev26~pkg4~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up mt7601-sta-dkms (3.0.0.4-0~201602170733~rev26~pkg4~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Loading new mt7601-3.0.0.4 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-47-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-47-generic
Done.

mt7601Usta:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
```

at this point I cannot do `modprobe mt7601Usta` because it is not there. neither is `mt7601u`. they are all gone. so I check `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory and it is blacklisted with `blacklist-mt7601u.conf`. (only this one). When I reboot the system wireless is not working (no driver). so I delete this file and it goes back to using `mt7601u` but not `mt7601Usta`.

At this point if I try `modprobe mt7601Usta` it gives me an error `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert Invalid argument`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation

Answer (score 0):

There is a Ubuntu 16.04.1 package in [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/mt7601?field.series_filter=xenial) that matches your hardware ID (148F:7601):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:thopiekar/mt7601
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mt7601-sta-dkms
```

This should contain the DKMS.

Source Post: [Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation)

Comment: firmware still missing and it just installed same driver which was in use

Comment: I downloaded firmware from [here](https://github.com/porjo/mt7601u/commits/master/src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin) and then did `cp src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin` but lshw still shows "N/A"

Comment: Did you try running `sudo modprobe mt7601Usta`?

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7601Usta': Invalid argument

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at a bit of a loss now.  Did you check the the Source post?  There are a could of other solutions in there that may be of more help.  :(

Comment: yeah but unfortunatley I cannot undesrtand why it is not working. gonna dig more and update

Comment: I updated my question