# Trying to get 148f:7601 Ralink WIFI running, supplied module on 16.04LTS doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, ralink

Right.  I'm trying to get my RALINK Wifi Nano to run on Kubuntu 16.04, it used to function on 14.04 using a driver I compiled from a git repo belonging to someone called porjo.

I've upgraded to 16.04 today, and the supplied driver (mt7601u) doesn't operate my device.  According to this link (a previous answer, https://askubuntu.com/a/690576/648189) apparently in 16.04, it just works.

**Newsflash:** *It doesn't.*

The old driver was mt7601Usta, the new one simply won't activate any wifi connection whatsoever, my device just sits there like the last brioche in a boulangerie.  Any ideas? I need my install connected to the net and without buying a new wifi adapter or fixing this, right now I'm shot.

Any help would be welcomed, as long as I can make this thing work!!! Thank you :)

Comment: "Newsflash: It doesn't." doesn't tell us much. How about telling us all of this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide that information without being on the net, since it requires that I'm connected to the internet to access the URL contained within.  Can you think of information which I can give you locally from the machine, without needing network access please?

Comment: You can see [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082305&p=12350385&viewfull=1#post12350385) as it has instructions for running it without an internet connection

Comment: Got it, Jeremy. Thanks for that. I'll reboot now and run that, and see you back here with all the info in a short while.  See ya :)

Comment: Right guys, here you go, the results of the wireless-info script.

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23888752/

Comment: The required module isn't loaded. What is the response to this terminal command? `sudo modprobe mt7601u && dmesg | grep mt76`? Firmware??

Comment: Did you use the PPA to install that module from the linked question?