# How to Set Up mt7601U USB Wifi Adapter in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

EDIT
I was using ubuntu 17.10. The following are the output. I have a USB Wi-Fi adapter MT7601U.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 082: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


$ sudo iwconfig
enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.


$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [1179:0002]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
```

I tried searching in Google and some says that this Wi-Fi adapter should automatically work when it is inserted. But not on my end.

What is the other configuration I need to do?

I also tried the instruction on this link
[Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation)

EDIT::

I downgraded my ubuntu to 16.04 to test if what says on the link above was true but unfortunately the same issue.

Here is the output for lsmod | grep mt7

```
$ lsmod | grep mt7
mt7601u               102400  0
mac80211              782336  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,mt7601u
```

No output for `sudo rfkill list all`

Here are the other output for 16.04 command

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 109: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


$ sudo iwconfig
enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.



$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [1179:0002]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
```

Comment: Which driver is loaded now? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsmod | grep mt7` And also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555 thanks for your time. I updated my question

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep mt7` Firmware??

Comment: @chili555 here is the result for that command mt7601u               102400  0
mac80211              782336  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,mt7601u

Comment: @chili555 I included that also on my updated question

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep mt7` Firmware??

Comment: mt7601u is the usb adapter model I think. During boot there are errors showing like this. "mt7601u Err MCU resp"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72110/discussion-between-chili555-and-yves-gonzaga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on this issue on github 
https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u/issues/64#issuecomment-352250127 works for me.