# Install Driver Software for 802.11n USB WiFi adapter in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, usb, ralink

I am trying to install a device driver for a RaLink USB WiFi adapter
(ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.).  The instructions are incomprehensible.

Finally figured out the instructions (complicated), but when I try to "make" the driver, I get error 1 and error 2 output.  It doesn't tell me what is wrong, though I suspect some files are missing from the directory.  That doesn't even make sense.  What do exit codes error 1 and error 2 mean?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please try this instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation/554278#554278

Comment: I have updated my question.  I have installed the driver, but my Ubuntu 14 still does not recognize the network adapter.

Comment: Please clarify. Did you try the process in my link? Did 'make' and 'sudo make install' go well? Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep 7601`

Comment: No.  Make install did not work.  I was unable to install the driver due to errors 1 and 2.  It also said “exiting directory” in two places in the output.  I also have no other internet connection available at home.

Comment: It is impossible to troubleshoot without more complete details; however, I suggest that you download the .iso for Ubuntu 16.04.4 and I'm confident that your device will work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm downloading the .iso right now.  I'll let you know how it works.