# Ralink RT2870/mt7601u Wifi Dongle not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb-modem, ralink

so... my problem is with this little guy that turned into a big headache. I tried EVERY forum post and countless Linux Distributions and i had the same problem, i cant make this Ralink wifi dongle to work, the dongle dont even appear in lsusb or dmesg. Is like the ubuntu dont want to see him connected... Btw, the dongle works, i tried in my main computer with windows 10 Home and the windows recognize the dongle. But in Linux it's completely no-deal, i running Ubuntu 18.04 in my old laptop, an Dell Inspiron N5110(obs: i fisically removed the native laptop wifi card because the antenna cables where damaged).

This is my last weapon to try to win this fight against a wifi dongle, i expect you guys could help me, thanks.

And sorry for my english, it isn't my main language.

Comment: Have you checked https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation ?

Comment: yep, nothing happens, some commands doesnt work

Comment: If you do not tell us what you tried and what doesn't work exactly it will be hard to help.

Comment: i tried to install the driver to ralink dongle works(driver is: mt7601u), but everything i tried was in vain, i really tried every post on the internet, from 20010 to 2017 and nothing worked for me.

Comment: in the majority of the posts that i tried to follow, the guy that was in need of help said that the dongle was appearing in "lsusb" and mine doest even appear, that is what i doesnt understand