# Ralink Technology, Wireless adapter MT7601U (Mercury MW150UH USB) not working

Tags: 18.04, wireless, mediatek

Ubuntu version:18.04
Kernel version:5.0.0
Wireless USB adapter:Mercury(Mw150UH)

[image: Ralink Technology]

[image: Kernel version]

I don't really understand what I'm doing. I tried to do [Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation) But didn't work. Also tried NDISwrapper didn't work. 
Mercury MW150UH USB adapter works on Windows 10 with no problem.

```
unuruu@unuruu-Inspiron-3520:~$ usb-devices |  awk '/7601/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 15 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=148f ProdID=7601 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=MediaTek
S:  Product=802.11 n WLAN
S:  SerialNumber=1.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=160mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 8 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
```

Result is nothing

```
unuruu@unuruu-Inspiron-3520:~$ dmesg | grep mt76
unuruu@unuruu-Inspiron-3520:~$
```

What else can I try?

Comment: It should work without any external drivers on the 5.0 kernel. Using ndiswrapper was a bad idea and may confuse things now.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text from a terminal. Instead copy text, paste it to your question, select it and press `{}` icon to format it. Please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/7601/' RS=` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 as you mentioned I added output

Comment: @Jeremy31 there is nothing to shows by that command

Comment: It looks like the mode of the dongle is not switched properly. It is detected as a flash drive. Does it mount as one? If it does, unmount it and see what happens. Dirver in `usb-devices` should change to mt7601u.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm sorry how do i unmount and mount it ? it doesn't show any disk.

Comment: `Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0; interface class is 255, expected 8. Abort`
it has got error

Comment: Unplug it, wait a minute, plug it in, wait a minute then `dmesg | tail -30 | nc termbin.com 9999`  post termbin URL

Comment: @Jeremy31 this is url  `https://termbin.com/yhxx`

Comment: ndiswrapper was uninstalled

Comment: What URL for>  `modprobe -c | grep 7601 | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: `https://termbin.com/escs`
link

Comment: need another one `grep [[:alnum:]] /etc/modprobe.d/* | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: `https://termbin.com/dce8` here

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-mt7601u.conf` reboot, plug the adapter in, wait a couple minutes and then `dmesg | tail -40 | nc termbin.com 9999` post URL

Comment: URL `https://termbin.com/cm9a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/mt7601u.git
sudo dkms add ./mt7601u
sudo dkms install mt7601u/1.0
```

Reboot and plug the USB in.  This will only fix the vendor request errors in the 5.0 kernels but the module should work.

This also works for EDUP-MS8552S

Comment: Why don't you add a `dkms.conf` to automate the "kernel update" procedure?

Comment: Ok, done.  Might use it for my cheap dongle, cost an entire $6.57

Comment: `unuruu@unuruu-Inspiron-3520:~$ sudo dkms install mt7601u/1.0

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)
'make' all KVER=5.0.0-36-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for mt7601u: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/mt7601u/1.0/build/make.log for more information.` And what that mean???

Comment: Let me install a 5.0 kernel and take a look

Comment: Ok, fixed that do `sudo dkms remove mt7601u/1.0 --all` then `cd ~/mt7601u && git pull` then `sudo dkms add .` be sure to include the . on that command, then `sudo dkms install mt7601u/1.0`

Comment: @Jeremy31 now it is working. Thank you for your hard work. And i didn't understand what you did.

Comment: I have a similar device that I recently got working thanks to comment 53 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1716301  At least we aren't using Ubuntu 16.04 with the 4.4 kernel as that needed usb-modeswitch and a udev rule to get it to switch from the 148f:2878 to the 148f:7601