# Downgrade Ubuntu 20.04 kernel from 5.4 to 3.2

Tags: 20.04, kernel, downgrade

Hi i need to downgrade Ubuntu kernel version to 3.2 because kernel 5.4 doesn't see my wifi driver package. I tried this command to see kernel images:

```
uname -r
```

But it only shows kernel versions that are above 5. I tried this command to download kernel 3.2:

```
apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic
```

and it shows error

[image: unable to locate package]

I couldn't find any solution by searching. How can I downgrade it to kernel 3.2? Do I have to uninstall completely and reinstall Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: You can't install kernel 3.2 in any current release and you absolutely NOT should even think of using an obsolete one like 12.04. If "kernel 5.4 doesn't see my wifi driver package" you're asking the wrong question. The question you should be asking is for help with the WiFi and it should start by posting the relevant hardware information about it.

Comment: Change your question to 'how to make kernel 5.4 see my wifi driver'.  That is what you need to know/do.  Have you enabled ubuntu restricted extras and check if there are any 'additional drivers' for your system?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Here are my drivers :  https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1U_i7u495ymtNb7TmkurnoI_KNT5J_4vF     I spent like 1 whole day to install it on my current kernel but i gave up afterwards

Comment: That means that code is ancient. The device is either natively supported now or there's a driver somewhere else or it's not to be used at all. That said, on a closer look at your screenshot it says "virtualbox". Are you in a VM and expecting to "see" the host's WiFi? If so that's a different issue

Comment: @ChanganAuto no i use it on an actual device but i don't have wifi there. I opened virtualbox just to test how can i downgrade kernel version. I bought wifi adapter one month ago from a store. Seems like the it was made in 2014. I cannot buy new one because there is no other electronic store near me

Comment: @crip659 the wifi drivers are pretty old. So i don't think it will be there. I will still try it

Comment: What a relief (about this isn't a VM)... The question, again, should be how to make WiFi work in Ubuntu XX.XX, not about downgrading kernel nor using unsupported releases. Basically you're doing/asking the exact opposite of what you should be doing. Try this script https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108, post results in a proper question, additional hardware info is welcome. The approach you're taking in this one is nonsensical.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i will try it. Thank you for taking your time to answer)

Comment: Feel free to post at Ubuntuforums.org especially if you need guidance and a back and forth discussion is advisable. The forum format is probably a better fit. Either way, please start by identifying your hardware (the script will do) and ask the right question as I already explained.

Comment: @Kyoko Sasagava  Ubuntu does better with older drivers than new ones, gives Ubuntu time to enable/make drivers that work in the newer kernels.  Have an very old P4 type laptop that Ubuntu still have drivers for.

Comment: @crip659 Of course, but in this case the OP is saying the WiFi doesn't work so the kernel still hasn't drivers for it but it shouldn't be hard to find new drivers in a PPA. Git, etc. The old code however is not to be used, end of story. But we need to identify that particular hardware first.

Comment: Hey all, I think there is a case for answering this question to the effect that downgrading to an ancient kernel is never the correct approach, with a detailed explanation of why.

Comment: I found the same driver here https://lab-tech.com.pl/mtk7603/ . I downloaded it and tried to install it using #sudo apt install and every file name in the package. But it didn't install either. I also used different commands and spent my whole day on it until i got stressed out and gave up. https://lab-tech.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/MT7603U_DPA_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20140825.zip That is the driver i downloaded. I don't have lots of hope that they updated their code because their website even is on wordpress

Comment: Did you consider a newer HWE kernel instead? It might work.

Comment: @ArturMeinild i read somewhere that ubuntu 19.04 may support it. I will try to install 19.04, install package then upgrade it to ubuntu 20.04 again. Idk if it will work or not. I just hope

Comment: @crip659 it is a usb wifi driver though. If it was my laptops own wifi driver it probably would work

Comment: @ChanganAuto the newest code that i found is this one https://lab-tech.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/MT7603U_DPA_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20140825.zip and it is similar to the drivers in my cd

Comment: At last we have an ID for the suspect: mt7603u. The only good news. I'm afraid this will never work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible answer by @Zanna suggestion.

The end-goal of the question is to make work a WiFi dongle with the infamous **Mediatek chipset mt7603u**, information gathered after a lengthy discussion in comments.

It isn't (and never was) supported in the Linux kernel therefore it requires manually installed drivers. Mediatek once provided such drivers that sort of worked (compilation errors, missing firmware, etc.) for old and out-of-support distros running kernel 2.6 - 3.2. In Debian/Ubuntu particularly it was hard to get it right and most users ended up buying a new one, cheaper, better and already supported ("plug'n'play"). Unlike its [mt7601u](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation) sibling that by the time of Ubuntu 16.04's release had full support, this one never had and Mediatek quickly relegated it to the legacy category and never updated the proprietary driver, a very unfortunate situation.

**Downgrading the kernel and/or using an obsolete End-of-Life Ubuntu release is never the answer.** EoL releases don't get security updates and are dangerous to use online. EoL releases are very unlikely to support newer hardware also. Downgrading the kernel can't be done for the same reasons (EoL, unsupported) and that simply wouldn't work with a current release.

I'm afraid that given all the above, the best solution is to ditch that old (and not very good anyway) WiFi dongle and acquire a known good "plug'n'play" one. That said the OP may want to post another question with the hope of attracting the house experts (@chili555 @jeremy31 - the ones I know, please don't be offended if I din't mentioned your name). A proper question would include the mention of the chipset from the get go and at least the `lsusb` result showing the exact VID:PID of the dongle or the more extensive result of the [wireless script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108) mentioned in comments.

Comment: it actually works pretty good in windows. My problem is i cannot buy new wifi because i am currently in a small town and there are no other electronic stores here

Comment: @KyokoSasagava No doubt it works in Windows, that was never the problem. PS - Have you heard of Amazon?