# USB Wifi dongle issues

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, usb-modem

sorry I'm new to all of this, so I'm after some help from the experts.

I've installed Ubuntu on the raspberry pi 4 and it boots and everything is working well from a device side.

But I have a USB Wifi dongle that I need to connect so I can set it up as an access point to run some tests.

The dongle is visible in lsusb but it isn't visible anywhere else;

I presum the hardware is blocked and thats why it's not coming up and visible in lshw but thats just a guess.

I did also wonder if the issue was drivers, but if I go to the driver GUI in the desktop it suggests that there are no drivers to install.

Can anyone help at all?

For info-

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0488:00df Cirque Corp. GlidePoint
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-interface:0
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 43430
       vendor: Broadcom
       physical id: 1
       bus info: mmc@1:0001:1
       logical name: mmc1:0001:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: dc:a6:32:e4:d5:ee
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.241 firmware=01-703fd60 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       logical name: eth0
       serial: dc:a6:32:e4:d5:ec
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=5.15.0-1015-raspi duplex=full ip=192.168.1.237 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s

$uname -r
5.15.0-1015-raspi
```

not sure what else you will need to know.

Comment: I suppose a follow up to this question is if I get this working any suggestions on how to configure the AP portion as I have been struggling with this in RasPi and thats why I moved to the Ubuntu build option.

Comment: According to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation the old chipset should just work now with any current Ubuntu release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)